# Simplify fraction within a fraction (Precalculus)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify $$\frac{x-2}{x-2-\frac{x}{x-\frac{x-1}{x-2}}}$$

My attempt:

$$=\frac{x-2}{x-2-\frac{x}{\frac{x(x-2)-(x-1)}{x-2}}} \ \ = \  \ \frac{x-2}{x-2-\frac{x}{\frac{x^2-2x-x+1}{x-2}}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{x-2}{x-2-\frac{x^2-2x}{x^2-3x+1}}$$

$$ =\frac{x-2}{\frac{(x-2)(x^2-3x+1)-(x^2-2x)}{x^2-3x+1}} \ \ = \  \ \frac{x-2}{\frac{x^3-3x^2+x-2x^2+6x-2-x^2+2x}{x^2-3x+1}} $$

$$ =\frac{(x-2)(x^2-3x+1)}{x^3-6x^2+9x-2} \ \ = \ \ \frac{x^3-3x^2+x-2x^2+6x-2}{x^3-6x^2+9x-2} $$

$$ =\frac{x^3-5x^2+7x-2}{x^3-6x^2+9x-2} $$

But the answer is given as $ \ \frac{x^2-3x+1}{x^2-4x+1} \ $, so I went wrong somewhere but can't see it. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Your numerator and denominator can each be factored and there are factors of $(x-2)$ that cancel.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way can you tell me how you made the equation fonts bigger?

Comment: Since it is your question, you should be able to click to edit the post and see the LaTeX that @boojum used to put your expressions in display mode. In my answer, maybe you can click to edit that too (or maybe it won't let you until your rep is higher).

Comment: In case you aren't able to look at the edited MathJax, I used "double-dollarsigns" at each end of the lines to set them  separated from text.  The "single-dollarsigns" for placing mathematical expressions in lines of text make it pretty tough to read characters two or more "size levels" down from the main font size (exponents and subscripts, especially).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the comments I explain how your answer is fine, just not simplified yet.

The way I would have simplifed this though avoids that issue. And you may like to study this technique.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{x-2}{x-2-\frac{x}{x-\frac{x-1}{x-2}}}
&=\frac{x-2}{x-2-\frac{x}{x-\frac{x-1}{x-2}}\cdot\frac{x-2}{x-2}}\\
&=\frac{x-2}{x-2-\frac{x(x-2)}{x(x-2)-(x-1)}}\\
&=\frac{x-2}{x-2-\frac{x(x-2)}{x^2-3x+1}}\cdot\frac{x^2-3x+1}{x^2-3x+1}\\
&=\frac{(x-2)\left(x^2-3x+1\right)}{(x-2)\left(x^2-3x+1\right)-x(x-2)}
\end{align}$$
All those $(x-2)$ cancel now, before you would expend effort multiplying out.
$$\frac{x^2-3x+1}{x^2-3x+1-x}$$

Comment: I probably would have canceled $x-2$ between the second and third lines.

Comment: Something that might be mentioned is that when "cancelation of factors" occurs in simplifying a rational function, the resulting expression is no longer _strictly_ equivalent to the original one.  The result should properly be written as $$  \frac{x^2 \ - \ 3x \ + \ 1}{x^2 \ - \ 4x \ + \ 1 } \ \ , \ \ x \ \neq \ 2 \ \ . $$  This particularly becomes an issue when we get to matters of discussing limits of functions.

Comment: An idea of this solution (and precalculus in general) is that you want to learn when it is useful to factor a polynomial and when it is useful to distribute/expand a factored polynomial.

Comment: @boojum the original function is undefined at $x = 2$ already though. So I think this is a moot point

Comment: @Alborz Yes, the _original_ function is undefined there, but the cancelation of the factor $ \ (x - 2) \ $ loses this information $ \ ( \ \frac{x^2 - 3x + 1}{x^2 - 4x + 1} \ \ $ _is_ defined for $ \ x = 2 \ $ ), so the inclusion of the condition $ \ x \ \neq \ 2 \ $ in the simplification serves as the indicator of the (removable) singularity.  (This is certainly not "moot".)

Comment: @boojum you're right

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct.... Sort of!

The answer you arrived at, can be simplified further to arrive at the answer you wish to achieve, since your attempt is completely valid. So, we have:

$$\frac{x^3-5x^2+7x-2}{x^3-6x^2+9x-2}$$

$$\frac{x^3-5x^2+7x-8+6}{x^3-6x^2+9x-8+6}$$

$$\frac{(x^3-8)-(5x^2-7x-6)}{(x^3-8)-(6x^2-9x-6)}$$

$$\frac{(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)-(5x^2-10x+3x-6)}{(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)-(6x^2-12x+3x-6)}$$

$$\frac{(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)-[5x(x-2)+3(x-2)]}{(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)-[6x(x-2)+3(x-2)]}$$

Factoring out $(x-2)$ from the numerator and denominator and canceling them out, we get:

$$\frac{x^2+2x+4-5x-3}{x^2+2x+4-6x-3}$$

$$\frac{x^2-3x+1}{x^2-4x+1}$$

And that's the desired answer.

Answer (score 0):

Less painful:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{x-2}{x-2-\frac{x}{x-\frac{x-1}{x-2}}}&=
\frac{x-2}{x-2-\frac{x(x-2)}{x(x-2)-x+1}}\\
&=\frac{(x-2)\bigl(x(x-2)-x+1\bigr)}{(x-2)\bigl(x(x-2)-x+1\bigr)-x(x-2)}.
\end{align}
$$
Now cancel by $x-2$ and multiply out to get
$$\frac{x^2-3x+1}{x^2-4x+1}.$$